# How to read a file line by line to a string type variable?

Tags: c++, iostream, fstream

I'm trying to read a file line by line to a string type variable using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


ifstream file(file_name);

if (!file) {
    cout << "unable to open file";
    exit(1);
}

string line;
while (!file.eof()) {
    file.getline(line,256);
    cout<<line;
}
file.close();
```

it won't compile when I try to use String class, only when I use `char file[256]` instead.

how can I get line by line into a string class?

Comment: Note how James checks the stream. `std::getline` returns the stream, and streams can be checked that way: `while (file)`; this is the correct way. (Checking for `eof` is not.) See: http://punchlet.wordpress.com/2009/12/01/hello-world/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `std::getline`:

```
std::string s;
while (std::getline(file, s))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @ufk:  No, you were using the `istream::read` member function; you need to use the `std::getline` function, which is not a member function.