# Search and replace loop running too many times

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, text-files, nested-loops

I have this problem with my application. When my application runs its running 8-13 times instead of 1 time.

The main purpose of my program is to search for a line from a file`(filein)` with `string strTemp2`, load it to a temp string and replace it with the `string strTemp2 + "\t\t"+"test"` to `fileout`

```
    string strReplace = strTemp2;
    string strNew = strTemp2+"\t\tTest";
    ifstream filein("c:/hospitaldata/PatientDatabase.txt"); //File to read from
    ofstream fileout("c:/hospitaldata/PatientDatabaseTEST.txt"); //Temporary file
    if (!filein || !fileout)
    {
        cout << "Error opening files!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    string strTemp;
    //bool found = false;
    while (filein >> strTemp)
    {
        if (strTemp == strReplace){
            strTemp = strNew;
            //found = true;
        }
        strTemp += "\n";
        fileout << strTemp;
        //if(found) break;

    }
```

**The input file for this purpose(c:/hospitaldata/PatientDatabase.txt):**

```
CPR             Patient nr      Værelse nr      Seng nr     Medicin
140143211       256             6               5
```

*The output file I generate now is:*

```
140143211       256         6           5               Test
140143211       256         6           5               Test
140143211       256         6           5               Test
140143211       256         6           5               Test
140143211       256         6           5               Test
140143211       256         6           5               Test
140143211       256         6           5               Test
140143211       256         6           5               Test
140143211       256         6           5               Test
140143211       256         6           5               Test
140143211       256         6           5               Test
140143211       256         6           5               Test
```

**The file I want to generate (c:/hospitaldata/PatientDatabaseTEST.txt)**

```
CPR             Patient nr      Værelse nr      Seng nr     Medicin
140143211       256             6               5           Test
```

Comment: Just write to the out file once, after the loop? The `<<` operators does what it's told each time you call it.

Comment: What value does strTemp2 have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a file line by line to a string type variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581761/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-to-a-string-type-variable)

Comment: You are outputting data each time you read a word from the input. 12 words, 12 lines.

Comment: strTemp2 have these values:

140143211       256             6               5

Comment: @Basilevs If you have time, please give a solution, where i only replace when the specific line is read.

Comment: @Andrew, please ping me again tomorrow, if you won't have a question by then.

Answer (score 0):

Read lines, not words:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

void markTest(istream & input, ostream & output, const string & pattern) {
    string strTemp;
    while (std::getline(input, strTemp))
    {
        if (strTemp == pattern){
            strTemp += "\t\tTest";
        }
        output << strTemp << "\n";
        if (!output) {
            break;
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    istringstream input(
        "CPR             Patient nr      VÃ¦relse nr      Seng nr     Medicin\n"
        "140143211       256             6               5");
    markTest(input, cout, "140143211       256             6               5");
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/tEDSm9

Comment: If i am right the output is now predefined. It may not be. 

The numbers 140143211 256 6 5 are changable.

Comment: @Andrew, markTest's output is definitely not predefined. It accepts any kind of as its argument, and you are free to supply filestream as such.You can also add fourth argument to append to found strings.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to to loop through once than you have to put a break inside the if condition.

```
while (filein >> strTemp)
    {
        if (strTemp == strReplace){
            strTemp = strNew;
            break;   // breaking the loop
            //found = true;
        }
        strTemp += "\n";
        fileout << strTemp;
        //if(found) break;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You write to the output file every cycle of the loop, not only when you find a match. This should work:

```
string strReplace = strTemp2;
string strNew = strTemp2+"\t\tTest";
ifstream filein("c:/hospitaldata/PatientDatabase.txt"); //File to read from
ofstream fileout("c:/hospitaldata/PatientDatabaseTEST.txt"); //Temporary file
if (!filein || !fileout)
{
    cout << "Error opening files!" << endl;
    return 1;
}

string strTemp;
filein.getline(strTemp);
fileout << strTemp << std::endl;

//bool found = false;
while (filein >> strTemp)
{
    if (strTemp == strReplace){
        strTemp = strNew;
        strTemp += "\n";
        fileout << strTemp;
        //found = true;
    }
    //if(found) break;
}
```

Comment: From the desired output in the question I think the OP also wants to output the first row.

Comment: Yes i want, that would be impportant

Comment: I edited my code to include adding the first line beforehand.

Comment: Try it again with the edited code. It uses `getline` to read the first line now, it should work.

Comment: Woops, sorry about that. Name should have been firstLine. I don't have access to a compiler right now so I can't actually test the code myself.

Comment: I would have used strTemp for the first line instead of the extra firstLine variable.

Comment: Error 1 error C2661: 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::getline' : no overloaded function takes 1 arguments ....\consoleapplication1\main.cpp 223 1 ConsoleApplication1

Comment: Try: `getline(filein,strTemp);`

Comment: OUTPUT:

CPR   Patient nr  Værelse nr  Seng nr  Medicin

I am not getting "test"